# Why does Sharepoint continually reformat HTML?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, sharepoint

I am utilizing a Sharepoint CMS for the first time, and I am perplexed by the constant re-writing of my content to include the crazy jump characters like "?" and "nbsp".  Can somebody please tell me how to get rid of this nuisance.

An example of this phenomenon is at http://techfests.com/NWA/2012/Speakers/JeffAmerine/default.aspx

You'll notice that apostrophe's become question marks.  Spaces become nbsp, etc.

Comment: SharePoint does those weird changes? At least the question mark issue looks more like an encoding problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use separate webparts (from Media and Content category) for content on page like: Image Viewer for photo and Content Editor for text.